# how to get jquery greyscale to work

Tags: jquery

I need to get an array of images to greyscale on hover , I'm not fluent with jQuery , and basically just do html/css , so i initially used filters but forgot IE 10 and IE 11 do not support them anylonger , so read a tutorial on implementing this effect with jQuery , but i'm running into wall trying to get this to work.

I set up jsfiddle with existing script, html , css - http://jsfiddle.net/zcsbvbk6/

I then added the grey-scaling below from a tutorial i read online , but it just doesn't seem to work no matter how many times i edit it into the existing script i'm using.

Any help on my fiddle to get this implemented ?

```
    $("#nitrohemletbar img").animate({opacity:1},500);

    // clone image
    $('#nitrohemletbar img').each(function(){
        var el = $(this);
        el.css({"position":"absolute"}).wrap("<div class='img_wrapper' style='display: inline-block'>").clone().addClass('img_grayscale').css({"position":"absolute","z-index":"998","opacity":"0"}).insertBefore(el).queue(function(){
            var el = $(this);
            el.parent().css({"width":this.width,"height":this.height});
            el.dequeue();
        });
        this.src = grayscale(this.src);
    });

    // Fade image 
    $('#nitrohemletbar img').mouseover(function(){
        $(this).parent().find('img:first').stop().animate({opacity:1}, 1000);
    })
    $('.img_grayscale').mouseout(function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({opacity:0}, 1000);
    });     
});

// Grayscale w canvas method
function grayscale(src){
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var imgObj = new Image();
    imgObj.src = src;
    canvas.width = imgObj.width;
    canvas.height = imgObj.height; 
    ctx.drawImage(imgObj, 0, 0); 
    var imgPixels = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    for(var y = 0; y < imgPixels.height; y++){
        for(var x = 0; x < imgPixels.width; x++){
            var i = (y * 4) * imgPixels.width + x * 4;
            var avg = (imgPixels.data[i] + imgPixels.data[i + 1] + imgPixels.data[i + 2]) / 3;
            imgPixels.data[i] = avg; 
            imgPixels.data[i + 1] = avg; 
            imgPixels.data[i + 2] = avg;
        }
    }
    ctx.putImageData(imgPixels, 0, 0, 0, 0, imgPixels.width, imgPixels.height);
    return canvas.toDataURL();
}
```